# Meteor: Fixing console is undefined in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, meteor

I tried fixing the error as has been suggested in other SO answers, but I continue to get the error. Any ideas why?

I tried using the following fix from here: ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer) and sticking it in a Meteor.startup in a client-side js file, but it didn't work.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  /**
   * Protect window.console method calls, e.g. console is not defined on IE
   * unless dev tools are open, and IE doesn't define console.debug
   */
  (function() {
    if (!window.console) {
      window.console = {};
    }
    // union of Chrome, FF, IE, and Safari console methods
    var m = [
      "log", "info", "warn", "error", "debug", "trace", "dir", "group",
      "groupCollapsed", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "profile", "profileEnd",
      "dirxml", "assert", "count", "markTimeline", "timeStamp", "clear"
    ];
    // define undefined methods as noops to prevent errors
    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
      if (!window.console[m[i]]) {
        window.console[m[i]] = function() {};
      }    
    } 
  })();
});
```

Should I be sticking this code somewhere else?

Comment: why not do it outside of the `Meteor.startup`? So the package init code doesn't throw ReferenceError's?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the code outside the `Meteor.startup()` function. This has to execute before you call `console.log` anywhere.