# JavaScript error : "there was an error with this field's customized event"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am using MS CRM 2013. I created a marketing list and tried to open it. A popup with error was thrown.
It was working fine and suddenly stopped.
Screenshot is as below;
[image]

Comment: IE does not define a console object unless the console is open.

Comment: Check the answer here to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer

Comment: It was working with IE9 and IE10. Suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Add an if-statement checking for console.