# How does this old jQuery function cause some error messages to be suppressed?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

This is a "please help me understand X" question, not a "please help me fix X" question.

I was doing some work on a site with a legacy proprietary CMS that only works with jQuery 1.4.4 (ugh) when I realised my code must be **hitting an error, but no error messages were showing in the console** (in all browsers I tried - Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE...).

Lots of trial and error later, I figured out that within any code triggered by jQuery 1.4.4's `mouseenter` event (and therefore also its `hover` shorthand), errors weren't being shown in the console. `console.log` still logged just fine, and the code would fall over as would be expected, but silently.

I don't understand how this is possible. I'd like to know how it is possible so that, if in future I end up in a similar position where code is hitting silent errors, I know what to look for - and so I know how to avoid causing a similar situation by accident.

---

### Prior research

I've tried searching for old jQuery bug reports, which might include relevant information, but I couldn't find any. I've read through a lot of SO questions from people trying to cause JS error suppression, but the answers suggest it's a user preference that couldn't apply to some lines of code but not others. I've looked through the [jQuery 1.4.4 source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js), but nothing looks relevant to my eye.

**I'm not interested in fixing the problem (that's as simple as updating jQuery)** - but I'd like to understand what causes this to happen, because I can't see how it's possible.

---

### Simple live demo

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.mouseenter').mouseenter(function(){
      console.log("FAIL .mouseenter");
      FAIL; // fails silently
      console.log("hit error, so this code isn't reached");
     });
     $('.mouseover').mouseover(function(){
      console.log("FAIL .mouseover");
      FAIL; // shows error as expected
      console.log("hit error, so this code isn't reached");
     });
    });
```

```css
div { height: 60px; background: #c1c1c1; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="mouseenter">mouseenter - hides error on hover</div>
<div class="mouseover">mouseover - shows error on hover</div>
</body>
```

After mouseovering around the console looks like this - `mouseover` shows error in console, `mouseenter` doesn't, but both hit the error and fall over:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old jQuery 1.4.4 used to wrap the code that did the mouseenter/mouseleave events in a `try{}catch(e){}` that throws away the error: See https://github.com/jquery/codeorigin.jquery.com/blob/master/cdn/jquery-1.4.4.js#L2487

You'll see that behavior until the effects rewrite that went in for jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

To add to gnarf's excellent answer - if you do find yourself in this situation, where you're not getting error messages due to a library calling your code within a `try{}catch(){}` that discards the error, and editing or upgrading the library is not an option, you can force the errors to show by wrapping all your code in another `try{}catch(){}` block that sneaks the error past the `catch()` by sending it straight to `console.error()`, for example:

```
            $('.mouseenter').mouseenter(function(){
                    try{
                            // your code
                    } catch(e){
                            console.error(e);
                    }
            });
```

If you're in the unfortunate position of needing to leave this in production code or of using IE during development, you should be aware that in many versions of IE `console` is by default undefined unless developer tools is open, so to avoid your error handling causing errors, instead use `if(window.console){console.error(e);}` or [use a robust proper fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13817235/568458).

---

### Demo

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.mouseenter').mouseenter(function(){
                    try{
                            console.log("FAIL .mouseenter");
                            var fail = FAIL; // fails silently
                            console.log("...");
                    } catch(e){
                            console.error(e);
                    }
            });
            $('.mouseover').mouseover(function(){
                    console.log("FAIL .mouseover");
                    var fail = FAIL; // shows error as expected
                    console.log("...");
            });
    });
```

```css
div { height: 60px; background: #c1c1c1; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="mouseenter">mouseenter - hides error on hover</div>
<div class="mouseover">mouseover - shows error on hover</div>
</body>
```