# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am developing a website on visual studio 2010 and its working fine on google chrome. But when I am trying to run on Internet Explorer for checking java script its giving following error-

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'console' is undefined

Even a blank project crashes on Internet Explorer. I have repaired visual studio but the error came out every

Comment: I've read before that IE only has a console object available to the code if the dev-tools are open. Does opening the dev-tools and then reloading the page still give you the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes  @enhzflep,on opening of dev-tools its still giving same behaviour. One thing I want to tell you on opening of any page this error comes on IE.

Comment: oh :( - which version of IE are you using? If you've not seen them already, these two questions may have some solutions you find helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472938/does-ie9-support-console-log-and-is-it-a-real-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer