# What would cause a "Message: 'console' is undefined" error to arise all of a sudden?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, console.log

I've been running my Sharepoint web page for a long time with no problems (well, not *this* problem), and today I got:

```
Message: 'console' is undefined
Line: 1124
```

Note: this problem was occuring in IE, but not in Chrome. In IE, Browser Mode is IE 8; Document Mode is IE 8 Standards (Page Default)

Line 1124 is the "console.log()" line below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('The ready function has been reached'); 
});
```

I found the solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer).

windowskm's comment below kennytm's answer says, "*place  if (!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};  at the top of your page!*"

I did that, and the error went away. But I would like to know why and *how* that problem popped up "out of the murky grey sky" (it's raining here in Santa Cruz as I keyboard this) - it's not just academic curiosity, but I'm wondering if whatever caused that issue might also have had some as-yet undetected deleterious effects elsewhere that I need to look out for.

IOW, one problem is solved using the solution above, but is there something deeper that I need to root out?

Comment: What do you mean? As I said, it's worked fine for weeks - why the sudden change? What could cause it?

Comment: @Mouser IE8 does have a console.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you using IE8 still?

Comment: That is simply the browser installed as the default on the Dev server; I much prefer Chrome, but many of our users are still on IE 8, and thus I have to test in a "lowest common denominator" mode.

Comment: Have you (or your organization) rolled out updates recently?  If so, one of those may have changed the default behavior or a setting value that affected the assumptions underlying your site's implementation.  One example might be to enable (or disable) intranet application compatibility.  When displayed in compat view, Intranet apps default to IE7 standards mode.  IE7 did not support a console, thus an error would occur.  The change you made prevented the call in such a case; that's why the error went away.  Perhaps the next question is what is the current doc mode and why?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, Document Mode is IE 8 Standards (Page Default). Why? I don't know - I didn't make it that, or change it. Should it be something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 8 will always throw that error if there is a call to `console.log` when the Developer Tools are not open.

Essentially, to IE 8, it is a null reference until the console is open.

Comment: It never happened before, and I virtually never have the IE Dev Tools open; if I want to look at the Dev Tools, I do so in Chrome.