# How to handle error 'console is undefined' in powershell?

Tags: javascript, powershell

Just a simple .js file in one of my drive which contains code

```
var x=3;
function numSqaure(x)
{
    return(x*x);
}
var sentence="The square of" + x + "is" + numSqaure(x);
console.log(sentence);
```

I'm trying to run it through Powershell but it shows an error *'console' is undefined* .

How to handle this error? I want it through Powershell only.

Comment: Please check this question for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer

Comment: it says *'window' is undefined*

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "run it through powershell"?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript files are made for being executed by a browser, not directly in console unless you're using Node.js or something similar.

Create an HTML with a script tag like this:

```
<script src="c:\whatever\folder\you\choose\yourscript.js"></script>
```

and enter developer tools in browser. There this error won't happen anymore and console will exist.