# In IE browser, React.Js JavaScript code works fine only after opening developer tools

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs

In IE, React.js javascript is not working in thin client but its working in localhost. why?

I am working on React.Js JavaScript code. In other browsers its working fine. But in IE browser, Its not working. But when we open developer tools, then its getting updated.

I tried to update values in IE. It didn't work. But after opening developer tools, It's getting updated.

Please help me out.

Comment: What version of IE? There's been a few of them over the years.

Comment: IE 10. I tried in latest too. But the result is same.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed the relevant code in your question?

Comment: Code is correct. Its working fine in other browsers.

Comment: In fact in IE, local machine its working. but in thin client its not getting updated.

Comment: Maybe some cache issue? Just add the code example..

Comment: In IE, React.js javascript is not working in thin client but its working in localhost. why?

Answer (score 0):

This commonly happens because `console` isn't available in older versions of IE unless the dev tools are open - the development build of React has lots of `console` logging with helpful warnings and errors.

You can use something like https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill to make sure your apps won't die when `console` logging is present.

See also answers to ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer).