# Log Javascript object as string Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to log the contents of an object using Logger.log in Google App Scripts?

If I have `Logger.log(data)`, the log is 'DataTableBuilder', or 'object' or something similar and incredibly unhelpful.

I want to see JSON strings of these objects if possible...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of [Nov 2013](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2013#november_2013), you can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert `Objects` into `String`s. Some Google documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#work_with_json), while the full JavaScript method documentation is available on your preferred API reference, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Example usage:

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Alternately, via Stackdriver Logging (as of [2017 June](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2017#june_23_2017)):

```
console.log({message: "Interactive object serialization", theObject: obj})
// or
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

I keep coming to this thread looking for a neat way to log nested objects and arrays in GAS. I needed an output like this:

```
{
    food : {
        pizza : [
            crust,
            sauce,
            topping,
            cheese
        ]
    },
    drink : {
        bananaShake : [
            banana,
            milk,
            sugar
        ]
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is a more elegant solution: `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`. Thanks to @Zach's comment below.

In any case this is the function I was using earlier:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Display the passed object in the Logger
// @param {object} obj - object to be logged
// @param {string} log - (for internal use only) final output sent to the logger
// @param {number} count - (for internal user only) keeps track of the number of 
//                         iteration that the program is running in.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function logObj(obj, log, count) {
  var def = {};
  // Set default values to the passed arguments
  obj = obj == undefined? def : obj;
  log = log == undefined? '\n' : log;
  count = count == undefined? 1 : count;

  // If it's date object convert it to string
  if(obj instanceof Date) {
    obj = obj.toString();
  }
  // If it's a function represent it as a string
  if(typeof obj == 'function') {
    obj = 'function() {}';
  }
  // If it's an Object
  if(typeof obj == 'object') {
    var isArray = obj.constructor.name == 'Array';
    var length = 0;
    for(var i in obj) {
      length++;
    }
    if(isArray) log += '[';
    else log += '{';
    if(length) {
      log += '\n';
      var num = 1;
      for(var i in obj) {
        // add tabs based on which iteration the program is running in
        var tab1 = '';
        var tab2 = ''; // this is one tab less than tab1 
        for(var k = 0; k < count; k++) {
          tab1 += '\t';
          if(k < (count - 1)) {
            tab2 += '\t';
          }
        }
        log += tab1;
        if(!isArray) log += i + ' : ';
        log += logObj(obj[i], '', count + 1);
        if(num < length) {
          log += ',\n';
        }
        num++;
      }
      log += '\n' + tab2;
    }
    if(isArray) log += ']';
    else log += '}';
    // if it's not the first iteration, return the log instead of printing it
    if(count > 1) {
      return log;
    }
  }
  else if(count > 1) {
    return obj;
  }
  else {
    log = obj;
  }
  if(count == 1) {
    Logger.log(log);
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`?

Comment: Also. if you want it to print in a readable way, you can pass args to `JSON.stringify()`. i.e. `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`. Or in your case, `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2))`

Comment: @ZachSmith Thanks for the suggestion. It never occurred to me that there are other parameters to customize JSON.stringify(). Have updated my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

This a function I modified from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603987/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-var-dump-or-print-r-in-php):

```js
var Log = {

// Thanks to Amos Batto - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603987/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-var-dump-or-print-r-in-php

  /*
  dump() displays the contents of a variable like var_dump() does in PHP. dump() is
  better than typeof, because it can distinguish between array, null and object.  
  Parameters:
    v:              The variable
    howDisplay:     "none", "body", "alert" (default)
    recursionLevel: Number of times the function has recursed when entering nested
                    objects or arrays. Each level of recursion adds extra space to the 
                    output to indicate level. Set to 0 by default.
  Return Value:
    A string of the variable's contents 
  Limitations:
    Can't pass an undefined variable to dump(). 
    dump() can't distinguish between int and float.
    dump() can't tell the original variable type of a member variable of an object.
    These limitations can't be fixed because these are *features* of JS. However, dump()
  */

  dump: function(functionName, v, recursionLevel) {

      recursionLevel = (typeof recursionLevel !== 'number') ? 0 : recursionLevel;

      var vType = typeof v;
      var out = vType;

      switch (vType) {

          case "number":
              /* there is absolutely no way in JS to distinguish 2 from 2.0
              so 'number' is the best that you can do. The following doesn't work:
              var er = /^[0-9]+$/;
              if (!isNaN(v) && v % 1 === 0 && er.test(3.0))
                  out = 'int';*/

          case "boolean":
              out += ": " + v;
              break;

          case "string":
              out += "(" + v.length + '): "' + v + '"';
              break;

          case "object":
              //check if null
              if (v === null) {
                  out = "null";

              }
              //If using jQuery: if ($.isArray(v))
              //If using IE: if (isArray(v))
              //this should work for all browsers according to the ECMAScript standard:
              else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Array]') {  
                  out = 'array(' + v.length + '): {\n';
                  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                      out += repeatString('   ', recursionLevel) + "   [" + i + "]:  " + 
                          Log.dump(functionName, v[i], recursionLevel + 1) + "\n";
                  }
                  out += repeatString('   ', recursionLevel) + "}";
              }
              else { //if object    
                  sContents = "{\n";
                  cnt = 0;
                  for (var member in v) {
                      //No way to know the original data type of member, since JS
                      //always converts it to a string and no other way to parse objects.
                      sContents += repeatString('   ', recursionLevel) + "   " + member +
                          ":  " + Log.dump(functionName, v[member], recursionLevel + 1) + "\n";
                      cnt++;
                  }
                  sContents += repeatString('   ', recursionLevel) + "}";
                  out += "(" + cnt + "): " + sContents;
              }
              break;
      }

      Logger.log(functionName + ' - ' + out);

    return;

    // Private Functions
    // -----------------

    /* repeatString() returns a string which has been repeated a set number of times */ 
    function repeatString(str, num) {
        out = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            out += str; 
        }
        return out;

    } // Log.dump.repeatString()

  }, // Log.dump()
}
```

Comment: Very new to google scripts, but it looks like you're missing a function. When I run this, I get: "TypeError: Cannot find function finer in object [object Object]. (line 80)"

Comment: That was my personal logging function I forgot to take out. I've replaced it with Logger.log