# Why does this code return 3-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get Multiple values, so use *getValues* but it returns array unexpected dimentional. 
In below code, ***sheet*** is an object that got *SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Example");*

```
var rng = sheet.getRange(2,1,3);    
var rngVls = rng.getValues();

Logger.log(rng.getValue()); // log1
Logger.log(rngVls);         // log2
Logger.log(rngVls[0]);      // log3
```

I expected the results like below. ***log2 is what I want to get.***

> - log1 = Bravo
> - log2 = [[Bravo],[Charlie],[Delta]]
> - log3 = Bravo

But unexpected dimension appears like below. I cant understand why.

> - log1 = [Bravo,[]]
> - log2 = [[[Bravo],[Charlie],[Delta]],[]]
> - log3 = [[Bravo],[]]

Please help me, how can i get a 2-dimentional B-C-D array??

---

-added APOLOGY-

uhhhhhh   Im so sorry for wasting your time, Its just my stupid mistake.
I had read not 'Log' but 'Running transcript'.
I got what i want, thank you all kindness.      i feel so down lets code.

Comment: Provide `Logger.log(rngVls.length)` and `Logger.log(rngVls[0].length)`

Comment: Use the 4-parameter signature, i.e `2, 1, 3, 1`?

Answer (score 1):

`getValues()` is returning a 2D array. Don't rely on loging an object to the log to determine its attributes. Instead use the appropriate JavaScript 1.6 methods like `typeof`, `instanceof`, JSON.stringify(object), etc.

Example:

```
function logSomeThings(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = sheet.getRange(2,1,3);    
  var rngVls = rng.getValues();

  Logger.log('log1 %s', typeof rng.getValue()); 
  Logger.log('log2 %s', rngVls instanceof Array);
  Logger.log('log3 %s', rngVls[0] instanceof Array);
  Logger.log('log4 %s', typeof rngVls[0][0]); 
  Logger.log('log5 %s', typeof rngVls[0][0][0]); 
}
```

Result

```
[19-01-31 10:32:24:187 CST] log1 number
[19-01-31 10:32:24:188 CST] log2 true
[19-01-31 10:32:24:189 CST] log3 true
[19-01-31 10:32:24:189 CST] log4 number
[19-01-31 10:32:24:190 CST] log5 undefined
```

Regarding JSON.stringify(rngVls);

```
Logger.log('log6 %s', JSON.stringify(rngVls));
```

logs something like this

```
[19-01-31 11:02:20:061 CST] log6 [[1],["#N/A"],[2]]
```

Notes:

1. `getValue()` returns the top-left value of the referred range.
2. The Google Apps Script IDE doesn't has the same capabilities as other tools like the console of Google Chrome's Developer Tools.

Related

- [Which Edition of ECMA-262 Does Google Apps Script Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252409/1595451)
- [Log Javascript object as string Google App Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30895943/1595451)

Comment: thanks , your comment make me notice that I read some different text. (content is big benefits too)