# How can I change this DEBUG code to correspond to the window object as well?

Tags: javascript

**How can I change this DEBUG code to correspond to the window object as well?**

[What is the JavaScript equivalent of var_dump or print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603987/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-var-dump-or-print-r-in-php/11315561#11315561)

---

**OK**

> ```
> var hoge = new Object();
> hoge.q = "stack";
> hoge.lang = "js";
> hoge.state = 1;
>
> dump(hoge, 'body');
> ```

---

**ERROR**

> ```
> dump(hoge, this);
> ```

**ERROR**

> ```
> dump(hoge, 'window');
> ```

Comment: The second argument simply tells the function how to display the result, eg display in page or display in alert box. How would you use `window` in order to display the information?

Comment: I wanted to display the WINDOW object debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define repeatString also, did you?

```
function repeatString(str, num) {
    out = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        out += str; 
    }
    return out;
}
```

and only  `dump(hoge, 'body');` would be available to use

Comment: I had to define in advance. So it's not covered by WINDOW objects