# Does jQuery have a JSON/javascript object to HTML pretty print function similar to PHP's var_dump?

Tags: jquery, pretty-print

Does jQuery have a JSON/Javascript object to HTML pretty print function similar to PHP's var_dump? If yes, what is it?

Comment: Take a look at this SO Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517/is-there-an-equivalent-for-var-dump-php-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517/is-there-an-equivalent-for-var-dump-php-in-javascript

Comment: I looked at that before I posted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

jQuery does not (out of the box).

However, James Padolsey created [this prettyPrint](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/prettyprint-for-javascript/) which I really like.

Also, if you're using Firebug or Web Inspector (or similar), you can just type the object into the console, press <kbd>return</kbd>, and see a tree-dump of the object. To force a tree-view, call `console.dir(obj)`

Answer (score 4):

Although the accepted answer is correct that jQuery does not have a pretty print feature for JSON, [that feature is now included in out of the box javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript) through `JSON.stringify()'s` [space argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

**To print to HTML**, [wrapping the output with `<pre> </pre>` will preserve the line spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-PRE) for readability purposes.

```
var obj = {a:1, 'b':'foo', c:[false,'false',null, 'null', {d:{e:1.3e5,f:'1.3e5'}}]};
var str = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4) + "</pre>";

/* Returns
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": "foo",
    "c": [
        false,
        "false",
        null,
        "null",
        {
            "d": {
                "e": 130000,
                "f": "1.3e5"
            }
        }
    ]
}
*/
```

Comment: The question was to pretty print HTML, not to pretty print JSON.

Comment: See the note below my answer.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer to the question but I like this rather than having to use some other dependency.

Answer (score -2):

Using Jquery, you can have  `object.serialize()` to output an object. This is similar to `var_dump()` in php or `Zend_Debug::dump()` in Zend.