# jQuery getJSON basics

Tags: json, jquery, getjson

My first attempt at it, and the testing function does not seem to work:

```
$.getJSON('questions.json', function(data) {alert(data);})
```

I am trying to alert all the contents of the JSON file which is really short.
What am I doing wrong? and why am I getting `[object Object]`

Comment: What are you using on the server? What is `questions.json` returning?

Comment: This post answers your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517/is-there-an-equivalent-for-var-dump-php-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is a way of encoding an object as a string so that it can be passed around a network easily.  When jQuery receives a string containing JSON data, it deserializes it -- it turns it back into a Javascript object.  This object is passed to your success handler -- you're calling it `data`.

When you try to `alert` a Javascript object, it will give you `[object Object]`, rather than a readable form.

You should use a Javascript console as provided by your browser to debug data like this, with the `console.log` method.

Answer (score 2):

the value of **data** is a JSON object, so **data** itself, when passed via alert(); would dump as [object Object].

Try console.log(data); instead of alert();

For my debugging and testing I use firebug, which has a nice little console tab.

Answer (score 1):

you data is json object, so you are getting [object Object] as alert.