# Learn about a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an `[object Object]` being passed as an argument through a jQuery function and I want to learn more about it.  I don't want to know anything about this specific situation (unless there is no solution) but how to replicate something like php's `var_dump()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent for var_dump (PHP) in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517/is-there-an-equivalent-for-var-dump-php-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `console.log(your_object_instance);` and look in the [FireBug console](http://getfirebug.com/commandline) in FireFox. This also works with Chrome/Safari developers tools. You will learn everything you need about this object such as properties, methods, ...

Comment: Also, just a note that Chrome and IE9 also have consoles built-in (not sure about Safari). I know you know this, Darin, I just wanted to put it out there. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function odump(object, depth, max){
  depth = depth || 0;
  max = max || 2;

  if (depth > max)
    return false;

  var indent = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    indent += "  ";

  var output = "";  
  for (var key in object){
    output += "\n" + indent + key + ": ";
    switch (typeof object[key]){
      case "object": output += odump(object[key], depth + 1, max); break;
      case "function": output += "function"; break;
      default: output += object[key]; break;        
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox you can use Firebug, or if you're on Safari or Google Chrome you can use their developer tools / console. Then use the `console.log()` method to dump information about the object into the console:

```
console.log(obj);
```

or

```
console.log({test: "lalala"});
```