# jquery css right on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I tried to get the position of the element from right. I defined the following in CSS

```
.container {
   position: absolute;
   right: 8%;
   bottom: 7%;
}
```

I tried to get the position of the element from right using the following jquery code

```
$('.container').css('right');
```

which gives **142px** on chrome and mozilla

but gives **8** (percentage) on iOS(both safari and chrome) browsers.

Any other options in jQuery to get the value in px on iOS browsers and other browsers alike?

Answer (score 0):

take the percentage and get the value...

```
var px_right = ('.container').css('right');
/* --- but --- */ 
if ( /*iOS*/ navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
    px_right = (('.container').css('right'))/100.0  * window.width();
}
```

`

**EDIT**
sorry I have forgotten a thing: `/100.0`. Edited:

`px_right = (('.container').css('right'))/100.0  * window.width();`

`example  : 'px_right = 8% of 980px = 0.08*980 = 78px`

Comment: i checked whether the result contains 'px' in it. if so, i let it be as it is. or I calculate the value depending on the enclosing container width... Thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
var style = Window.getComputedStyle($('.container')[0])
console.log(style.right);
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me... it says Window.getComputedStyle is not defined

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206924/unable-to-access-style-with-getcomputedstyle-in-ios