# How to inspect/dump Ionic variables

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to inspect the `$ionicTabsDelegate` variable on my hybrid app using this "dump" solution which can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517/is-there-an-equivalent-for-var-dump-php-in-javascript).

```
function dump(obj) {
    var out = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
        out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }

    alert(out);

    // or, if you wanted to avoid alerts...

    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.innerHTML = out;
    document.body.appendChild(pre)
}
```

But once I call my dump function, I'm getting this error on the console:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So, how can I check this object?

Answer (score 1):

You might have tried the top voted solution and run into errors, because it tried to access just whatever too often.

You could give the [answer by @PPrice a try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7034412/1587329) (worked fine on some occasions) and just use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myVar)); // or whatever you want to do with myVar
```

`JSON.stringify` should avoid circular dependencies and such.