# Randarray not definied

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to create a two dimensional Array - but in the JS console it keeps saying my "Randarray" function isn't defined. I can't seem to figure out why it's undefined, maybe I just need another pair of eyes to look over it.

Any help is appreciated!

## Part 2

```
<button id="array" onclick="Randarray()"> Array </button> 

<script>
function Randarray()
{
randarray = new Array(5)
randarray [0] = new Array(3)
randarray [0][0] = "Toyota"
randarray [0][1] = "1998"
randarray [0][2] = "Black"

randarray [1] = new Array(3)
randarray [1][0] = "Ferrari"
randarray [1][1] = "2006"
randarray [1][2] = "Red"

randarray [2] = new Array(3)
randarray [2][0] = "Ferrari"
randarray [2][1] = "2006"
randarray [2][2] = "Red"

randarray [3] = new Array(3)
randarray [3][0] = "Jeep"
randarray [3][1] = "2006"
randarray [3][2] = "Silver"

randarray [4] = new Array(3)
randarray [4][0] = "Mercedes"
randarray [4][1] = "2016"
randarray [4][2] = "White"

randarray [5] = new Array(3)
randarray [5][0] = "BMW"
randarray [5][1] = "2017"
randarray [5][2] = "Black"

function getArray(row,col){
document.arrayForm.myResult.value=randarray[row][col];

}

document.getElementById('array').addEventListener('click', Randarray);

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you adding the events twice?

Comment: And you have forgotten to close the `}` for the function.

Comment: i suggest you use some kind of linter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the `Randarray` function before the `getArray` function. Do this:

```
} // Missing.

function getArray(row,col)
```

Also, don't use event listener as well as `onclick` inline function.

```html
<button id="array" onclick="Randarray()">Array</button>

<script>
  function Randarray() {
    randarray = new Array(5)
    randarray[0] = new Array(3)
    randarray[0][0] = "Toyota"
    randarray[0][1] = "1998"
    randarray[0][2] = "Black"

    randarray[1] = new Array(3)
    randarray[1][0] = "Ferrari"
    randarray[1][1] = "2006"
    randarray[1][2] = "Red"

    randarray[2] = new Array(3)
    randarray[2][0] = "Ferrari"
    randarray[2][1] = "2006"
    randarray[2][2] = "Red"

    randarray[3] = new Array(3)
    randarray[3][0] = "Jeep"
    randarray[3][1] = "2006"
    randarray[3][2] = "Silver"

    randarray[4] = new Array(3)
    randarray[4][0] = "Mercedes"
    randarray[4][1] = "2016"
    randarray[4][2] = "White"

    randarray[5] = new Array(3)
    randarray[5][0] = "BMW"
    randarray[5][1] = "2017"
    randarray[5][2] = "Black"
  }

  function getArray(row, col) {
    document.arrayForm.myResult.value = randarray[row][col];
  }

  document.getElementById('array').addEventListener('click', Randarray);
</script>
```

Comment: Would my "getArray" function print out the array?

Comment: If your body contains a form with a name and id of arrayForm and an input with a name and id of myResult.

Comment: I tried adding that to my body but I can't seem to get it to work, could you elaborate a little more? (Sorry I'm still learning)

Comment: @DannyGarcia Can you make a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) with the code you have? Kinda tough to understand / explain why it isn't working.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsbin.com/qomexevawa/edit?html,output I basically just want the array I created to print out when I click the button. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DannyGarcia You still don't have the canvas element. Is this the whole code you have?

Comment: @Danny, you need to add form and input buddy... Come to chat.

Comment: @DannyGarcia Welcome! :) Final code here: http://jsbin.com/qojebenobu/edit?html,output

Comment: One last Q: how would I expand the form to print everything inside the array from (0,0) to (5,2) ?

Comment: @DannyGarcia Looks like you need something like ... `var_dump` of PHP?

Comment: @DannyGarcia Check [Is there an equivalent for var_dump (PHP) in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323517)...

Comment: I feel like there's an easier way to achieve it with the function we worked out before

Comment: @DannyGarcia How do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: Simply within the form

Comment: @DannyGarcia Using `JSON.stringify`, there's a way. I need to check.