# Is there a function/method in JavaScript to get detailed information about the content of a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is a function or method in JavaScript such as `var_dump()` in PHP that prints or returns detailed information about the content of a variable, i.e. value(s) and data type. Especially in case of more complex data types like arrays and objects such a function would be very helpful...

Comment: Did you research this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/323517/3001761, for example.

Comment: `console.log`…‽

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks for the link, I didn't use the term "var_dump" for searching via search engine, otherwise I probably would have found that that thread by myself.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, ```console.log()``` is useful but it has to be used together with other functions/methods or attribute calls that only give a single information about the content of the variable...

Comment: If you're using node.js, you might be looking for [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options). In general, logging an object to the console does well, and you should [learn how to use a debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) in general

Comment: @gretarsson What do you mean by "*[`console.log`] has to be used together with other functions/methods*"?

Comment: I don't agree with this question being closed. That other answer is specifically for objects only, and doesn't address other data types.

Comment: @Bergi: For instance, in order to get the data type, you have to use ```typeof``` additionally. On the other hand, I just noted that ```console.log()``` prints the content of the variable even if its a complex data tape (which is not possible with ```echo``` in PHP or ```System.out.print()``` in Java). From that the data type becomes more or less obvious...

Comment: @gretarsson Try `console.log("%o", x)` to distinguish primitives (it wraps strings in quotes). But yes, the JS console does not just print text to stdout if you have attached a debugger.

Comment: @Bergi: But ```console.log("%o", x)``` only(?) works in GoogleChrome, not in Firefox et al. However, numbers apparently can be distinguished form strings by color in the console...

Comment: Yes, when you are logging to `console` it depends on your environment what exactly will happen with the value - in any case it tries to output a helpful representation. If whatever is available doesn't satisfy you, you will have to write your own formatting function - there is no builtin one in JavaScript (unless you count `JSON.stringify`).